# Linux command running JAVA with cronjob

Tags: java, linux

I'm trying to setup a cronjob (cPanel) that execute a shell file which will run java application. However I can't get the class path to work.

JAVA folder application path

```
/home/user/public_html/version_1/data/downloader
```

This command inside .sh file is working when running through terminal and  inside the JAVA application folder

```
java -cp .:download.jar:log4j.jar:commons-httpclient.jar:commons-fileupload.jar:commons-logging.jar:commons-codec.jar:JAxe-1.0.jar portal.client.Main login
```

However when running outside the folder it doens't work and returns the following error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class portal.client.Main
```

so I try to specific class path

```
java -cp /home/user/public_html/version_1/data/downloader/*:.download.jar:log4j.jar:commons-httpclient.jar:commons-fileupload.jar:commons-logging.jar:commons-codec.jar:JAxe-1.0.jar th.or.set.portal.client.Main login
```

It still showing error

```
log4j:ERROR Could not read configuration file [log4j.properties].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: log4j.properties (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:297)
    at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configure(PropertyConfigurator.java:315)
    at portal.client.Main.main(Main.java:32)
log4j:ERROR Ignoring configuration file [log4j.properties].
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (portal.controller.MainController).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:117)
    at portal.client.DownloadParameter.parseLoginParam(DownloadParameter.java:177)
    at portal.controller.MainController.execute(MainController.java:45)
    at portal.client.Main.main(Main.java:130)
```

Comment: You run the code in a wrong directory

Comment: Show the code around `at portal.client.DownloadParameter.parseLoginParam(DownloadParameter.java:177)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well. You need to change workdir. You may do it simply by using [`cd`](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/cdh.html)

```sh
cd /home/user/public_html/version_1/data/downloader/
java -cp .:download.jar:log4j.jar:commons-httpclient.jar:commons-fileupload.jar:commons-logging.jar:commons-codec.jar:JAxe-1.0.jar portal.client.Main login
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried creating a script to set your environment up and then fire your java program?

your script would look something like :

```
#!/bin/sh
export CLASSPATH=<paths to files>
java <your program>
```

You can drop your script into the crontab then and twiddle with it as much as you like without having to update your entry.

Comment: How does it help to fix problem with file serced in current dir is absent?

Comment: it helps because it allows the script to be modified without having to mess about with the crontab constantly

Answer (score -1):

You can set the class path in the manifest file of your jar package

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: myapp
Implementation-Version: 1.0.1
Class-Path: lib/dep1.jar lib/dep2.jar
```

then you can run your jar file without passing any additional arguments

Comment: It wont fix problem with file searched in current dir is not found?

Comment: @talex why set the path of log4j.properties in class-path wont fix the problem?

Comment: Because main problem is `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: InputStream cannot be null` which I suspect is wrong file path.